# Amazon Lex - Enabling responses from Slack mentions

Tags: chatbot, slack-api, amazon-lex

I am creating an Amazon Lex bot as a POC to see what it can do. I have a version of the bot working where I can direct message it and receive responses back. The logging for both Lex and Lambda shows the conversations that are occurring.

I decided to move forward and attempt the same conversation by inviting my bot to a public channel I created. In doing so, I added app_mentions:read, channels:history, chat:write, and chat:write.customize permission to my bot via the OAuth scopes in the app configurations.

When trying to mention my app, the amazon lex logs do not show a conversation is occurring nor is the lambda function executing. It appears that slack is either not receiving the request or the request never calls lex, to begin with.

Does anyone know what is required for slack configurations to at minimum have it call Lex? I don't know if it is reading the mentions though I would think so because it has permissions.